# sugarCRM order by ignored

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

I changed the default column that one of the modules is ordered by. Now I would like to have the order to show up in a specific order. I have created a view.list.php file and placed it in the custom/module/view folder. When I override the listViewPrepare() function to select the column with:

```
 $_REQUEST['orderBy'] = 'table.column';
```

it works fine. When I change the code to:

```
$_REQUEST['orderBy'] = "FIELD(table.column, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7')"
```

it does not order by at all.
I have checked the syntax of the order by statement in mysql and it works there but when I insert it into the view.list.php it doesn't work. I have echoed out the variable and it is in there correctly. I don't understand why it isn't working.

thanks
Alex

Comment: How many values are there in the table

Comment: No, how many columns are in the table, and how many values are you trying to order by

Comment: I am pulling 10 columns from two tables that have a combined total of 154 columns. I am only sorting on one of columns that has one of seven possible values.

Comment: Are you really passing it using 'value1' as an alias for a field?

Comment: here is the actual variables:  'NHSactive', 'Hands_Off', 'NHSsubmitted', 'NHSIncomplete', 'NHSCancelled', 'NHSComplete', 'NHSClosed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have manually sorted the list view by clicking the up or down arrows on the title of a field, SugarCRM will save this as the last used ordering field and use it the next time you view the list. Try clicking 'Reset User Preferences' from your user page.

Comment: I have noticed that it saves that sort until you reset. Unfortunately that is not causing the issue that I am having. Thanks for the reply, I was thinking yesterday that I should post to this question to try to keep it active.

Answer (score 1):

This is your syntax: You are missing open and close quotes on the first column

```
$_REQUEST['orderBy'] = "FIELD(Contacts_cstm.file_status_c, 'NHSactive', 'Hands_Off',     'NHSsubmitted', 'NHSIncomplete', 'NHSCancelled', 'NHSComplete', 'NHSClosed')";
```

I believe this is how it should be...give it a try...also $query should be your select statement

```
$query.=" ORDER BY ".$_REQUEST['Contacts_cstm.file_status_c, 'NHSactive', 'Hands_Off',     'NHSsubmitted', 'NHSIncomplete', 'NHSCancelled', 'NHSComplete', 'NHSClosed'];
```

Comment: I am hoping you have a typo in there somewhere because you have an open quote just inside the [. The syntax in my original line is correct. ORDER BY FIELD(fieldName, 'value1', 'value2' etc. I am not sure why you have the $_REQUEST object in your line of code. I am overriding the listViewPrepare function which checks if the $_REQUEST['orderBy'] object is set, so I am setting it to the value that I want then calling the parent, from there it is creating $query and making the database call. My order by field(... call works perfectly when I run it in mysql but not inside the sugarCRM.